# What's the best way to stop a batch script after a specified amount of time?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10, command-prompt

I'm writing a batch script where I want the user to be able to control how long the script runs. When running it from the command line, the user will pass in a switch like this:

```
./myscript --stop-after 30
```

which means that the script will keep doing its job, and check every iteration how much time has passed. If more than a half a minute has passed, then it'll quit. How would I implement this in a batch script?

For reference, here is the code I have so far:

```
:parseArgs

if "%~1" == "" goto doneParsing

if /i "%~1" == "--stop-after" (
    shift
    set "duration=%~1"
)

:: Parse some other options...

shift
goto parseArgs

:doneParsing

:: Now do the actual work (psuedocode)

set "start=getCurrentTime"
set "end=%start% + %duration%"

while getCurrentTime < %end% (
    :: Do some lengthy task...
)
```

How would I go about implementing the latter part of the script, after parsing the options?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: It largely depends on the nature of the lengthy task. If it is something which is repeated until an event occurs and you can have the task detect that event, it would be handled differently from a process that requires to be forcefully terminated,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not that trivial. You'll have to do a lot of calculation within your script to cover all cases of full minute, full hour, or even new day. I can think of two different ways. Both are based on two batch files:

#### 1. Termination via `taskkill`

`starter.bat`:

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="" (
    set duration=5
) else (
    set duration=%1
)
start "myscript" script.bat
ping 127.0.0.1 -n %duration% -w 1000 > nul
echo %duration% seconds are over. Terminating!
taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq myscript*"
pause
```

`script.bat`:

```
@echo off
:STARTLOOP
echo doing work
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 -w 1000 > nul
goto STARTLOOP
```

For this solution, it's important that you give the window executing your script a unique name inside the line `start "myscript" script.bat`. In this example, the name is `myscript`. `taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq myscript*"` uses `myscript` to identify which process to terminate.

However, this might be a bit dangerous. Your script will be killed after *x* seconds, no matter if an iteration is done or not. So, *e.g.*, write access would be a bad idea.

#### 2. Termination via flag file

`starter.bat`:

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="" (
    set duration=5
) else (
    set duration=%1
)
if exist terminationflag.tmp del terminationflag.tmp
start script.bat
ping 127.0.0.1 -n %duration% -w 1000 > nul
echo %duration% seconds are over. Setting termination flag!
type NUL>terminationflag.tmp
```

`script.bat`:

```
@echo off
:STARTLOOP
echo doing work
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 -w 1000 > nul
if not exist terminationflag.tmp goto STARTLOOP
del terminationflag.tmp
echo terminated!
```

Here, it's important to ensure that your script is allowed to create/delete a file at the current location. This solution is safer. The starter script will wait the given amount of time and then create the flag file. Your script will check after each **full iteration** whether the flag is there or not. If it's not, it will go on—if it is, it will delete the flag file and terminate safely.

In both solutions `ping` is used as timeout function. You could also use `timeout/t <TimeoutInSeconds>` if you are on Windows 2000 or later. However, `timeout` doesn't always work. It will fail in some scheduled tasks, on build servers, and many other cases. You'd be well advised to stick to `ping`.